# Is magnetic susceptibility mere number in case of linear material and a tensor in case of non-linear material?

Tags: electrostatics

In electrostatics,it was taught to us that the electric susceptibility is mere number in case of linear dielectric materials.(So direction of polarization and electric field created due to that polarized material is same.)
But in case of non linear material,electric susceptibility acts as a tensor (and above two directions are no more same.)
Does the same hold true for magnetic susceptibility?

Comment: I am not an expert but is there confusion about non-linear vs. anisotropic here? Don't they mean different things? You seem to be describing the anisotropic property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Typically, crystals tend to have anisotropic magnetic susceptibility tensors. But even individual atoms can have one. This has actually important applications in Nuclear Magnetic Resonance (NMR) studies of proteins by putting them in solution with e.g. lanthanide ions which exhibit such a highly anisotropic magnetic susceptibility tensor then, and this can then be used to facilitate resolving the protein structure.

Comment: Microwave ferrites are non-isotropic, have tensor permeabilities, but possess excellent linearity over a large dynamic range, see filters, isolators, circulators and phase shifters based on ferrites.